# Sorting an array using qsort()

Tags: c, arrays, struct, integer, qsort

I am trying to check if two arrays contain the same elements. Since I don't know if the input file is sorted correctly I want to use `qsort()` to sort the array first and them compare it against the array `cmpvalues`.

However I can't get `qsort` to sort the array like the array `cmpvalues`. The array where the values are stored should be sorted like the array `cmpvalues` so that it's a lot easier to compare.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXCOLR   14
#define MAXLINE  100
#define MAXCHR  1024   
#define _GNU_SOURCE

typedef struct {
    char color[MAXCOLR];
    int value;
} colorval_t;

int cmpfunc(const void *a, const void *b) {
    int aa, bb;
    aa = *(int *)a;
    bb = *(int *)b; 
    return (aa - bb);   
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    size_t n;
    int cmpvalues[] = {
        65,
         2,
         3,
         4,
         5,
         6,
         7,
         8,
         9,
        10,
        74,
        81,
        75,
        65,
         2,
         3,
         4,
         5,
         6,
         7,
         8,
         9,
        10,
        74,
        81,
        75
    };
    size_t ndx = 0;
    char buf[MAXCHR];
    colorval_t arr[MAXLINE] = {{ .color = "" }};

    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen(argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) { 
        perror("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }

    while (ndx < MAXLINE && fgets(buf, MAXCHR, fp)) {
        char c;
        if (sscanf(buf, "%13s %d", arr[ndx].color, &arr[ndx].value) == 2)
            ndx++;
        else if (sscanf(buf, "%13s %c", arr[ndx].color, &c) == 2) {
            arr[ndx].value = c;
            ndx++;
        }
    }
    if (fp != stdin)
        fclose(fp);   

    for (size_t i = 0; i < ndx; i++)
        printf("arr[%2zu] : %s %d\n", i, arr[i].color, arr[i].value);

    //sorts the array
    qsort(arr, 26, sizeof(arr[26]), cmpfunc);
    for (n = 0 ; n < 26; n++) {   
        printf("%d ", arr[n].value);
    }

    //checks if arrays have the same element
    int j;
    for (j = 0; j < 26; j++) {
        if (arr[j].value != cmpvalues[j]) {
            printf("wrong");
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

input:

```
RED A
RED 2
RED 3
RED 4
RED 5
RED 6
RED 7
RED 8
RED 9
RED 10
RED J
RED Q
RED K
BLACK 10
BLACK J
BLACK Q
BLACK K
BLACK A
BLACK 2
BLACK 3
BLACK 4
BLACK 5
BLACK 6
BLACK 7
BLACK 8
BLACK 9
```

Comment: You pass `colorval_t *` to qsort, yet your `cmpfunc` expects `int*` argument. The `cmpfunc` does not sort according to your `cmpvalues` array just only subtracts the `int`s. You need to change it to compare `coloarval_t` values and also take the color into account. You need to define `_GNU_SOURCE` _before_ any `#include` statement for it to work. You are just lucky `sizeof(arr[26])` works and is valid, however I can guess it doesn't mean what you think it means. You have posted the input to your program - please post the output of your program and the expected output of you program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comparison function is wrong.

The [`qsort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) function passes pointers to the elements in the array you sort, so if you have an array of `colorval_t` then the arguments are of type `colorval_t *`.

Since you treat the pointers are `int *` you have a mismatch, and that will lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

That means your comparison function should look something like

```
int cmpfunc (const void * a, const void * b) {
    colorval_t *first = (colorval_t *) a;
    colorval_t *second = (colorval_t *) b;

    return first->value - second->value;
}
```

Comment: `return first->value - second->value;` is incorrect: subtracting `int` values coud overflow, causing undefined behavior. You could instead write: `return (first->value > second->value) - (first->value < second->value);` which is defined for all arithmetic types.

Comment: It is also advisable to avoid removing constness to prevent warnings: use `const colorval_t *first = (const colorval_t *)a;`...